# Jenkins input on declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

may I ask if it is do-able if I can get the user input and run a script based on what was chosen by the user? the logic whould be

> IF User choose **Proceed** THEN run a script (in my case promote or Blue/Green deployment)
>   IF User choose **Abort** THEN don't terminate the jenkins job, run a script (in my case rollback)

This is the script I'm using however I have no idea how to apply after validate stage

```
  pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh """#!/bin/bash +x
          echo "performing sts assume role"
          //SCRIPT-HERE//        
          echo "performing ansible deploy"
          //SCRIPT-HERE//  
        """
      }
    }
    stage('validate') {
        steps {

            timeout(30) {
                script {
                    input(message: 'Please validate, this job will automatically ABORTED after 30 minutes even if no user input provided', ok: 'Proceed')
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }

}
```

One more issue I'm seeing is, although this pipeline script is running, The Proceed / Abort is not clickable on the jenkins job Console output, is it a bug? I'm referring to the image shown below

[image]

I was able to add nandilov's suggestion however it seems that the logic is still not applying, please advise on what is missed here

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh """#!/bin/bash +x
          echo "performing sts assume role"

          echo "performing ansible deploy"

        """
      }
    }
    stage('validate') {
        steps {
          script {
            env.flagError = "false"
              try {
              input(message: 'Please validate, this job will automatically ABORTED after 30 minutes even if no user input provided', ok: 'Proceed')

              }catch(e){
                println "input aborted or timeout expired, will try to rollback."
                env.flagError = "true"        
              }
          }
        }
    }

    stage("If user selects Proceed"){
        when{
            expression { env.inputValue == "value1" }
        }
        steps{
            sh """#!/bin/bash +x
              echo "User selected proceed"
            """
        }
    }

    stage("rollback if flag error true"){
        when{
            expression { env.inputValue == "value2" }
        }
        steps{
            sh """#!/bin/bash +x
              echo "User selected Abort"
            """
        }
    }

  }

}
```

from the pipeline view it never triggered either one of the last two stages when choosing "Abort" or "Proceed"

[image]

These are the logs when choosing Abort or Proceed

**ABORT**

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-job-lagot
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] sh
performing sts assume role
performing ansible deploy
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (validate)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] input
Please validate, this job will automatically ABORTED after 30 minutes even if no user input provided
Proceed or Abort
[Pipeline] echo
input aborted or timeout expired, will try to rollback.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (If user selects Proceed)
Stage "If user selects Proceed" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (rollback if flag error true)
Stage "rollback if flag error true" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

**PROCEED**

```
Started by user lagot
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-job-lagot
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] sh
performing sts assume role
performing ansible deploy
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (validate)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] input
Please validate, this job will automatically ABORTED after 30 minutes even if no user input provided
Proceed or Abort
Approved by lagot
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (If user selects Proceed)
Stage "If user selects Proceed" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (rollback if flag error true)
Stage "rollback if flag error true" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the job aborted and do something, you can try/catch it:

```
try{
    input(message: 'Please validate, this job will automatically ABORTED after 30 minutes even if no user input provided', ok: 'Proceed')
}catch(e){
    println "input aborted or timeout expired, will try to rollback."
    // execute rollback
}
```

You also can do it in another stage:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh """#!/bin/bash +x
          echo "performing sts assume role"

          echo "performing ansible deploy"

        """
      }
    }
    stage('validate') {
        steps {
          script {
            env.flagError = "false"
              try {
              input(message: 'Please validate, this job will automatically ABORTED after 30 minutes even if no user input provided', ok: 'Proceed')

              }catch(e){
                println "input aborted or timeout expired, will try to rollback."
                env.flagError = "true"        
              }
          }
        }
    }

    stage("If user selects Proceed"){
        when{
            expression { env.flagError == "false" }
        }
        steps{
            sh """#!/bin/bash +x
              echo "User selected proceed"
            """
        }
    }

    stage("rollback if flag error true"){
        when{
            expression { env.flagError == "true" }
        }
        steps{
            sh """#!/bin/bash +x
              echo "User selected Abort"
            """
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Hi nandilov, from the screenshot I provided it shows the user should only either click "Proceed" or "Abort" . I whould like to know if this logic can be possible  = 

IF User choose "Proceed" THEN run a deploy script else IF User choose "Abort" run rollback script.

(Deploy script and rollback scripts are my samples only)

Comment: Editted answer accordingly, My bad, before I just read that you wanted to get the value from input.

Comment: Hi nandilov, I think I'm almost there, however when I tried to choose either "Abort" or "Proceed" I'm still the expected script to run. I added your script blocks above, you may check my updated message above. I'm still tweaking the pipeline script and trying to make it work. ( google-ing resarch :-) )

Comment: Hi Lagot, check my latest edit. I had a typo on the variable name when I adapted it after my first approach on reading the user input. As you don't need, I think my recent edit will work on your side. let me know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, @nandilov. I was looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, you will need to click on Proceed and then to choose between "deploy" and "rollback". The result we'll be store in an environment variable and you can use it as a condition on the next stages

```
    stage('validate') {
        steps {
            timeout(30) {
                script {
                    CHOICES = ["deploy", "rollback"];    
                        env.yourChoice = input  message: 'Please validate, this job will automatically ABORTED after 30 minutes even if no user input provided', ok : 'Proceed',id :'choice_id',
                                        parameters: [choice(choices: CHOICES, description: 'Do you want to deploy or to rollback?', name: 'CHOICE'),
                                            string(defaultValue: 'rollback', description: '', name: 'rollback value')]
                        } 

                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        when {
            expression { env.yourChoice == 'deploy' }
        }
        steps {
            ...
        }
    }
    stage('Rollback') {
        when {
            expression { env.yourChoice == 'rollback' }
        }
        steps {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi robertobatts, your code worked when I tried. however when I click "Abort" the pipeline aborted too, I was thinking if this logic will be possible = IF User choose "Proceed" THEN run a deploy script else IF User choose "Abort" run rollback script. (Deploy script and rollback script are my samples only)